# What does this function converge to in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $D_i$ ~ $Bern(q)$. Let $\hat{q} = \frac{1}{N}\Sigma{D_i}$. Find the distribution of $\frac{N(\hat{q} - q)^2}{1-q}$ as N goes to infinity.

By Central Limit Theorem I have $dlim(\sqrt{N}(\hat{q} - q)) = N(0, q(1-q))$. Apply Continuous Mapping Theorem,  $N(\hat{q} - q)^2$ converges to $[N(0, q(1-q)]^2$. Is this Chi-squared distribution? If I divide by $q(1-q)$, what distribution would I get?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already stated, by using the CLT, continuous mapping and Slutsky, you have that 
$$
\frac{   \sqrt{n}( \hat{q} - q) }{\sqrt{q(1-q)} }\xrightarrow{D} Z, 
$$
such that $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hence, by using the continuous mapping for $g(x) = x^2$ once again, you have that 
$$
g \left( \frac{   \sqrt{n}( \hat{q} - q) }{\sqrt{q(1-q)} } \right) \xrightarrow{D} g(Z)=Z^2. 
$$
One of the definitions of the $\chi^2$ distribution is a square of the standard normal random variable, thus
$$
g(Z) =Z^2\sim\chi_{(1)}^2.
$$